# Communicating programatically over a telecommunicating alarm

Tags: automation, telephony, alarm

I own a Yale EasyFit alarm system which allows me to control it over a kludgy telephone interface (doc [here](http://www.yale.co.uk/en/yale/couk/productsdb/alarms/-easy-fit-alarm--accessories/easy-fit-telecommunicating-alarm---kit-2/))

Here's an excerpt of how it works:

```
Remote Access
The control unit allows you to control your system
remotely through the telephone line.
1 Dial the phone number associated with the Control
panel.
2 Hang up on the first ring.
3 Wait 5-10 seconds.
4 Dial the number again.
5 The control unit will answer the phone on the first
ring of that second call.
6 Enter your PIN Code within 3 seconds.
7 If the PIN code is correct, you will hear a long
beep. A list of different functions is detailed below:
Press 2 Put the system into away armed mode (arm
the system).
Press 3 Disarm the system.
Press 5 Checking the system status. Long single
beep for Away Armed, two beeps for Disarmed and
three beeps for Home Armed.
Press 7 Siren on.
Press 8 Siren off.
Press 9 or 0 Disconnect.
•   Remember to press 9 or 0 before you hang up, or
the control unit will hang up automatically after 30
seconds.
```

It seems like it should be straightforward to have a device which can simulate the ringing and send the key tones/listen to responses but I'm not sure what kind of equipment I should be looking for. I have a spare raspberry pi that I'd use as the main controller and connecting to any required equipment. Open to using any tiny form factor board for management.

Comment: Problem is its not simple, you would need something that can provide "talk battery" (line voltage), pass DTMF tones, and generate a telco style ringing signal (~90vAC superimposed on DC circuit), so to do this a computer you have few options, the most likely answer would be to use a SIP FXS gateway for the equipment side, and some kind of SIP server for the device to register such as Asterix, then essentially generation SIP "calls" to the device to send the digits you wish. You can't do this with a simple raspberry pi, it will require external hardware.

Comment: Yup, I'm not intending to do it all with a raspberrypi, what I mean is that I would simply be running the controlling software on a pi, and mentioned it as an option for connectivity to external hardware

Comment: Your problem is the interface, not the software. The interface is an analog, telephony interface using DTMF signaling and AC ringing indication. You can't really use a digital device to do that directly, you need an interface or adapter to do it, that is why a SIP gateway would be used.

Comment: That's the information I'm looking for:) Something like this? http://www.novavox.co.uk/voip-/-sip-gateways-ip-analog-adapters-grandstream-handytone-ht701-analog-adapter-p-164.html?gclid=CjwKEAiA3aW2BRCD_cOo5oCFuUMSJADiIMILdUsIHd6-G9crlHUHyf15K4WwVwtoWnvSZLLBVcCq7hoCoMPw_wcB

Comment: lol, yes, something exactly like that. :)

Comment: P'raps you want to add an answer instead of a comment? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device in question is intended to be operated by an analog phone line, to automate is use you will need to emulate that "interface" using a device you can control, in this case the easiest would probably be SIP FXS gateway.